# How to import project in Android Studio via terminal?

Tags: bash, android-studio, terminal, git-clone

Can anyone give me advice how to import project to Android Studio via terminal (or if the option above is possible)?

**Preconditions:** One have process ID of started Android Studio (for example *9600*) and project location (for example it is current location so one can use  *pwd*).

**Motivation:** To automatize usage of *git-cloned* project within Android Studio IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Android Studio, navigate your menu bar to ..

`Tools > Create Command-line Launcher...`

A dialog will show up so you click `ok` and you are all set.

From that you can do something like this to import cloned project from your terminal:

```
  $ git clone git@github.com:shaunkawano/AndroidProject.git 
  $ studio AndroidProject
```

Below is the reference I looked up to; although it is in Japanese it has screenshots and may help you more.

http://qiita.com/takahirom/items/e9ad33e94140b09855c3

I hope it helps.